# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable python with variable

Tags: python

i have variable `a`

`a = 349`

i can do `float(a)`

output is:

`349.0`

i can do `int(a)`

output is:

`349`

but with `str(a)` i have error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-bddfa438ffc2> in <module>
----> 1 str(a)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

why? str is basic method as i know. whats i'm doing wrong

Comment: Doing `str(a)` after `a = 349` works fine. You need to provide more details. What other lines of code are you running ?

Comment: it works for me: `a=349

int(a)
Out[5]: 349

float(a)
Out[6]: 349.0

str(a)
Out[7]: '349'`

Comment: `str` is uspposed to work, this means that you've accidentally overwritten `str` somewhere. make sure you dont have lines that do `str = ...` anywhere

Comment: @germanjke Please check if you have redefined `str` somewhere else in your code

Comment: thx @RishiDev problem was that i redefined str in my code.

Answer (score -1):

The code:

```
a = 349
a = int(a)
a = float(a)
str(a)
```

Works in jupyter as well as terminal repl.

Did you name another variable `str = 'whatever xyz'` somewhere in your code?